# How to upgrade postregsql-client on ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to use pg_dump that comes from postgresql.

Problem is I have the error `pg_dump: error: server version: 13.9; pg_dump version: 12.12 (Ubuntu 12.12-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)`

I tried to upgrade it with `sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-client-13` but I have errors like `E: Unable to locate package postgresql-client-13`

I tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` but nothing changed.

What can I do to upgrade the version in order to have 13.9 version (same version than server version) ?

Comment: Are you dumping over the network?  If not, how did you get a different version in the first place?  How to fix it depends on how you get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the file repository configuration:

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'`

Import the repository signing key:

`wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

Update the package lists:

`apt update` and `apt install postgresql-client-13`

Comment: Thanks, wget doesn't work. I'm behind a proxy